# vb.net - consume a web service in a .NET library

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I was trying to migrate a vb.net code to Windev, but I failed at consuming a web service.

The web service I'm trying to consume (h[ere is the url link to the wsdl file](https://www.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpgem-beta/billService?wsdl)) sends a zipped xml file, the response is a zipped xml file, says if the file I sent is accepted or not.

In this web service, I call the sendBill function, about the parameters :
- fileName : string value, contains the zip filename to send (the .zip extension is required)
- contentFile : byte array value, represents the zip file to send.

The returned value is a byte array value, represents the zip file received.

I'm trying to send [this zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/en2tl63u6iozkjb/20450835600-01-FF11-56.zip?dl=0), therefore the filename parameter value is 20450835600-01-FF11-56.zip

The call of the web service requires an identification, here are the id identifications :
username : 20450835600MODDATOS
password : MODDATOS

So, about my initial problem, I decided to consume the web service via a .NET library, here is the code of my library :

```
Public Class ServiceSunat
Private _ZIPFile As String
Private _ZIPFileResponse As String
Private _sunat_ruc As String

Public Property ZIPFile()
    Get
        Return _ZIPFile
    End Get
    Set(value)
        _ZIPFile = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ZIPFileResponse()
    Get
        Return _ZIPFileResponse
    End Get
    Set(value)
        _ZIPFileResponse = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property sunat_ruc()
    Get
        Return _sunat_ruc
    End Get
    Set(value)
        _sunat_ruc = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function SendZIPFile() As String
    Try
        If _ZIPFile = "" Then
            Throw New Exception("The ZIPFile value is missing")
        End If

        If _ZIPFileResponse = "" Then
            Throw New Exception("The ZIPFileResponse value is missing")
        End If

        If _sunat_ruc = "" Then
            Throw New Exception("The sunat_ruc value is missing")
        End If

        Dim NomFichierZIP As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_ZIPFile)
        Dim usernametoken_login As String = sunat_ruc & "MODDATOS"
        Dim usernametoken_pwd As String = "MODDATOS"

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = True
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = True

        Dim ws As New ServiceBeta.billServiceClient
        Dim Retour As Byte()

        Dim data As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_ZIPFile)

        ws.ClientCredentials.CreateSecurityTokenManager()
        ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = usernametoken_login
        ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = usernametoken_pwd

        ws.Open()
        Retour = ws.sendBill(NomFichierZIP, data)
        ws.Close()

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(ZIPFileResponse, Retour)

        Return ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = "" Then
            Return "Unknown error encountered"
        Else
            Return ex.Message
        End If
    End Try

End Function
```

End Class

About my app.config file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BillServicePortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="secured">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.sunat.gob.pe:443/ol-ti-itcpgem-beta/billService"
   binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BillServicePortBinding"
   contract="ServiceBeta.billService" name="BillServicePort" >
        <headers>
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken >
              <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXMODDATOS</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>MODDATOS</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The code to use my library :

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim EnvoiSunat As New SUNATbeta.ServiceSunat
    Dim l_messageRetour As String = ""

    With EnvoiSunat
        .sunat_ruc = "20450835600"
        .ZIPFile = "C:\Mes Projets\EnvoiWindev\20450835600-01-FF11-56.zip"
        .ZIPFileResponse = "C:\Mes Projets\EnvoiWindev\sunatResponse.zip"
        l_messageRetour = .SendZIPFile
    End With

    If l_messageRetour = "" Then
        MsgBox("ok")
    Else
        MsgBox(l_messageRetour, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If

End Sub
```

End Module

But I encounter this error message :

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceBeta.billService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I have no clue of what this error message stands for and how to solve this...

Thanks

PS :

1. this webservice is simply used to verify if the zip file sent can be accepted or not next time I'll try to send it via the production one
2. as it's a test webservice, every user has the exact same password, only the numerical part of the username can change